# .NET Core user secrets, project.json

Tags: .net-core, project.json

IHello everyone, I have a small problem, maybe someone can help me, i want to use dotnet user-secrets tool when i'm developing my .net core web app. I am done everything i read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets. In this doc there is a tutorial for .net core with csproj files but i have project.json, i worked it out but when i try to type in command prompt 'dotnet user-secrets list' in my prject folder i only get:

```
Could not find a MSBuild project file in 'C:\WebApp\src\WebApp'. Specify which project to use with the --project option.
```

I tried it with --project option but i got the same, did i forget to do something ?
Here You have part of my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0", 

    .......

    },

    .....

  "tools": {
    ...
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final"
  },

  "userSecretsId": "ee5f10b0-829f-4257-9024-e5ee6e085823",

  ......
}
```

Comment: For future searchers who may land here, I experienced a similar error for a newer project, one w/o the `project.json` file. In my case I opened the [Visual Studio 2022] "Tools | Command Line | Developer Command Prompt", after opening the solution. Noticing the `Specify which project to use with the --project option.` part of the error message, I did just that, added project specification: `--project <project folder>\<project>.csproj` and all was seemingly well.

Answer (score 1):

i have just found a solution of my problem, i was trying to use the newest version of user-secrets tool which works good with projects which have *.csproj files. I still have project.json files, and if i stay with my VS2015 i have to stay with *.json files ( I read somewhere that installation of new VS2017 is required for using *.csproj files in .net core - correct me if I'm wrong). I found a nice tutorial: https://www.janaks.com.np/user-secret-management-asp-net-core/ , I followed the instructions and use exactly the same versions of user-secrets tool and the same version of userSecrets dependency with my sdk version in global.json:

```
"sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
```

now everything works fine :)

Comment: thanks for this!  Works for me.  One thing I noticed: is that it gave me a warning that this particular version didn't exist but it auto-switched to: 1.0.0-preview2-final